# On improvements of the GPY sieve

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

When $\chi_\mathbb P(n)$ denotes the characteristic function of primes and $\mathcal H=\{h_1,h_2,\dots,h_k\}$ is some admissible $k$-tuple, the GPY sieve can be formulated as follows:
$$
S(x)=\sum_{x<n\le 2x}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{1\le i\le k}\chi_\mathbb P(n+h_i)-\rho\right)}_{v_n}w_n
$$
where $w_n$ is some nonnegative function, which is typically chosen to be the quadratic form appearing in Selberg's sieve. Reading through GPY's, Zhang's, and Maynard's paper, I see that the main improvements of this sieve occur in the choice of $w_n$, so I wonder whether there are researches dedicated to modifying $v_n$.

In the theory of combinatorial sieve, weights similar to the current choice of $v_n$ is called **Kuhn's weight**. I heard that many results (i.e. almost primes generated by polynomials) have been improved by replaceing Kuhn's weights with **Richert's weights**, so I am also curious whether such modification in sieve weights can be helpful on GPY sieve and the study of prime gaps.

Comment: Maybe look in the two Polymath papers? They put more effort into optimizing the details then the Zhang and Maynard papers  and might have considered this direction.

Comment: I just read the [Polymath paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1186/s40687-014-0012-7.pdf) that improves the gap to 246, and I found out in page 11 that the authors are also using the weights equivalent to $v_n$ in my question.

Comment: Such weights do little to change the main asymptotic behavior of the problem in question. Maynard played with this idea in one of his early papers on almost-prime k-tuples and got some minimal improvements for small k, but then he turned his attention to multi-dimensional w_n and the rest is history.

Comment: If you are referring to [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/3tuples-have-at-most-7-prime-factors-infinitely-often/73AED623A51262F35405200AFE938246), then it is still a bit different from this question as that paper uses combinatorial sieve instead of a more GPY-fashioned modern sieve.

Comment: No, even before that paper Maynard was playing with the combination you're interested in. See this paper here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4610